# Is RTLinux the same as linux-rt?

Tags: 10.04, kernel, realtime

I'm trying to install a hard realtime kernel in Lucid for some robotics work. My preference is RTLinux (http://rtlinuxfree.com) by Wind River Systems. I also see that there is a package by the name "linux-rt" in the repositories, and its description is: "complete Realtime (RT) Linux kernel".

My question is: are these two the same? If not, what are the differences between them and the pros and cons of each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if they are similar in name, but not exactly the same.

When looking at the Ubuntu package

http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid-updates/linux-rt

They reference "http://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_Patch " , which 404. Looking at http://rt.wiki.kernel.org, I eventually was directed back to

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RealTime

From the faq, the linux-rt kernel is no longer maintained, and is (was) based on the ubuntu (patched) kernel.

The page you referenced, RTLinux, looks like a separate project, based on a non-ubuntu, vanilla kernel.